# Post form in C# with checkbox

Tags: c#, post, checkbox

I'm trying to post data to a PHP page, i have this code in C#:

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["name"] = forumSubDomain.Text;
            data["domain"] = forumDomain.SelectedItem.ToString();
            data["forum_title"] = forumTitle.Text;
            data["username"] = forumUsername.Text;
            data["password"] = forumPassword.Text;
            data["password_confirm"] = forumPassword.Text;
            data["email"] = forumEmail.Text;
            data["tos"] = "yes";

            var response = wb.UploadValues(url, "POST", data);
        }
```

So, all values are being posted well, but the checkbox 'tos' isn't post as checked.

I have tried using a few other values than 'yes', but it didn't worked out.

Comment: did you try "true" or 1 ?

Comment: yep, both didn't work